# What is my C code not printing # in staircase pattern, this is from hackerrank, I did not pass all test cases, but i can't point out why?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

> Write a program that prints a staircase of size n.

I did not pass through all the test cases and don't understand where I made mistake.

This is my code:

```
void staircase(int n) {
    char a[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if((i + j) > ((n / 2) + 1)) {
                a[i][j] = '#';
                printf("%c", a[i][j]);
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Given Input
`6`
Expected Output

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

---

Explanation:

The staircase is right-aligned, composed of # symbols and spaces, and has a height and width of `n=6`.

Comment: Please provide the expected output and the output of your program here.

Comment: If you're using C language, who do you tag with C++?

Comment: What test case did you fail

Comment: testcase with `n == 1` should print a space or an octothorpe?

Comment: @Tarik Those are hidden test cases in which the code failed. The visible test cases passed.

Comment: @pmg it should print '#' as per my understanding

Comment: You should test edge cases and invalid/insane inputs.  That is a normal, and expected, stage of testing.

Comment: Your code prints a space when `n == 1` ... see https://ideone.com/GYEl8p ('_' used instead of space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the condition

```
if((i + j) > ((n / 2) + 1))
```

It should be

```
if(j >= n - i - 1)    // or   if(i + j >= n - 1)
```

To make this easier, I would create a helper function. Also, there's no need for the VLA `a[n][n]` that you don't even use for anything.

```
void repeat_char(int x, char ch) {
    for(int i=0; i < x; ++i) putchar(ch);
}

void staircase(int n) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {        
        repeat_char(n - i, ' ');   // or  printf("%*s", n - i, "");
        repeat_char(i, '#');
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the condition was mistaken. Your suggestion helped :)

Comment: The code you wrote is much simpler, but I'm a beginner I guess it'll take time to write such clean and easy codes.

Comment: @sb7 It may take some time to identify what parts you can break out and put into simple functions that does just one little thing like the `repeat_char` function, but always be on the lookout for those parts. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need your `a` variable to do what you need. Here is a sample achieving what you want:

```
void staircase(unsigned n)
{
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                for (unsigned j = 0; j < (n - i - 1); ++j)
                        printf(" ");
                for (unsigned j = 0; j < (i + 1); ++j)
                        printf("#");
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

The first loop is meant to cover every lines, then within it you make a loop which handles the spaces before the actual `#` symbols, and finally you make the loop handling the displaying of the symbols.

Comment: just a remark : to use *printf* to output one char is expensive for nothing, else you can ask *printf* to output the expected indent for the first # rather than to do yourself

Comment: Thanks for the remark, however wouldn't any modern compiler do the optimisation themselves ?

Comment: at that level this is not an 'optimization', you ask for too much ;-)

Comment: You'd be surprised ! Just checked by myself and it appears 9.3 does the thing ! Here is the compilation process and the assembly result: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zCzyNPCvQP/ ; Lines 148, 158 and 165 have the C code's `printf`'s replaced by `putchar`'s

Comment: in a way this is sad, anyway you cannot suppose you have that kind of compiler, better you do yourself isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way of going about this than what you are trying to do:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const int n = 6;
    char* str = malloc(sizeof(*str)*(n + 1));
    if (str == NULL) {
        printf("Somthing wrong with memory!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    memset(str, ' ', n);
    str[n] = '\0';
    for(int i = n - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        str[i] = '#';
        puts(str); //or maybe printf who cares
    }
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```